# How can I access this value from my Struct in my function? Swift

Tags: swift

I want to be able to pass in garrett or allegany, and call one of it's values but the dot notation I am using gives me mdCounties.type does not have a member named County transfer.  BUT I did create an an instance (garrett and allegany)???

```
  struct mdCounties {
    var countyRecordation: Double = 0
    var countyTransfer: Double = 0
}

let garrett = mdCounties(countyRecordation: 7.0, countyTransfer: 1.0)
let allegany = mdCounties(countyRecordation: 6.50, countyTransfer: 0.005)

func mDtransferTaxCalc(purchasePrice: Double, split: Bool,mdCounties) -> Double {
    let userCountyTransfer = (purchasePrice) * mdCounties.countyTransfer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mdCounties` is your type. You need an instance of the struct to access its instance methods. You also don't have your function parameters written correctly. Do this instead:

```
func mDtransferTaxCalc(purchasePrice: Double, split: Bool, counties: mdCounties) -> Double {
    let userCountyTransfer = (purchasePrice) * counties.countyTransfer
    return userCountyTransfer
}
```

Comment: wow so simple yet I wasn't close...thank you!!  yes I had left out the rest of the function for clarity on what I needed help with

Comment: Also, bonus tip: for singular entities use a singular name like `mdCounty` instead of what you've got now. If you're sharing your code with other programmers they could get confused and assume that mdCounties is an array of mdCounty variables.

Answer (score 0):

In your mDtransferTaxCalc parameter list, give a name for the mdCounties parameter and use that name inside the method.

```
    func mDtransferTaxCalc(purchasePrice: Double, split: Bool, county: mdCounties) -> Double {
let userCountyTransfer = purchasePrice * county.countyTransfer
}
```